# vim spellcheck: command or function to dump all bad words to file

Tags: vim, spell-check, data-dump

I frequently need to correct files that have numerous spelling errors. Spellcheck tags all these words, but is there a command or function within vim that will dump all these tagged words to a file?

Answer (score 1):

My [SpellCheck plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) provides a command that populates Vim's *quickfix list* with all spelling errors. This is even better than dumping to a file in that you can quickly locate each spelling error. It also sets up mappings in the quickfix list to "remotely" correct / add to spell dict the mistakes.

Comment: Karkat  Thank you for your response.  Afraid I decided there was no such command, so I wrote this mapping to do so `code` map <F10> qzq:w y<CR>:setlocal spell spelllang=en<CR>:let wds=""<CR>:while line('.')>=@z<CR>:let @z=line('.')<CR>:norm ]syw<CR>:let wds=wds.@".' '<CR>:endwhile<CR>:e y.vim<CR>ggdG:exe setline(1, wds)<CR>gg:s/ \+/\r/ge<CR>:sort u<CR> `code`  I need it as a file, y.vim, because I semi-automatically turn this into a vimscript of substitute commands